# To draw a surface with a curve

Tags: graphics3d

```
Clear[r, s, t, n, κ, r0, t0, n0];
eqns = {t'[s] == κ[s] n[s], n'[s] == -κ[s] t[s], 
  r'[s] == t[s], t[0] == t0, n[0] == n0, r[0] == r0};
κ[s_] := 2 Sech[s];
τ[s_] := 0;
{t0, n0} = Orthogonalize[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
r0 = {0, 0};
sol = First@NDSolve[eqns, {r, t, n}, {s, -5, 5}];
With[{s1 = (r /. sol)["Domain"][[1, 1]], 
s2 = (r /. sol)["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, 
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[r[s] /. sol], {s, s1, s2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thick, Brown}, PlotRangePadding -> 1]]
```

[image]

In addition to the above, there is such an equation.

```
Subscript[x, t] (s, t) = Cross[Subscript[x, s], Subscript[x, ss]] = \[Kappa] 
(s, t) b (s)
```

So, can we draw the surface X(s,t)?
Can you help me?

Comment: Changing the question after an answer was posted will not help you get help next time.

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{# , #2 Cos[t], #2 Sin[t]} & @@ (r[s] /. sol), {t, 
  0 , 2 Pi}, {s, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity@.5]
```

[image]