# a surface generated under certain conditions by means of a curve

Tags: graphics3d

```
Clear[r, s, t, n, κ, r0, t0, n0];
eqns = {t'[s] == κ[s] n[s], n'[s] == -κ[s] t[s], 
r'[s] == t[s], t[0] == t0, n[0] == n0, r[0] == r0};
κ[s_] := 2 Sech[s];
τ[s_] := 0;
{t0, n0} = Orthogonalize[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
r0 = {0, 0};
sol = First@NDSolve[eqns, {r, t, n}, {s, -5, 5}];
With[{s1 = (r /. sol)["Domain"][[1, 1]], 
s2 = (r /. sol)["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, 
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[r[s] /. sol], {s, s1, s2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thick, Brown}, PlotRangePadding -> 1]]
```

In addition to the above, there is such an equation.

```
Subscript[x, t] (s, t) = Cross[Subscript[x, s], Subscript[x, ss]] = \[Kappa] 
(s, t) b (s)
```

So, can we draw the surface X(s,t)? Can you help me?

Comment: What is `X(s,t)`, how is it related to the equation and how equation is related to the first code block. Can you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to do? It seems you've rephrased your older question [171408](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171408/5478) and my answers there is 'detached' now. Currently we have two exactly the same questions. Can you clean it up?

Comment: Before you do this I close this one as it is exactly the same.

Comment: This is a different question than the other. Here the curve is the same, but the X (s) curve evolves depending on the t time parameter. So he draws a surface. I can not draw this surface.

Comment: You edited the linked question and now both look exactly the same. Where is that difference you are talking about? I'm asking about the question body. All equations and sentences are the same, aren't they?

Comment: All the equations given for the curve are the same. But then the expression I added is different. There is a curve x (s) and its own Frenet frame. I am asking about the surface formed by evolving of this curve in the direction of b (s) binormal. \[Kappa ] is curvature of curve. t is time parameter.

Comment: Which expression is different? Both questions contain the same `Subscript[x, t] (s, t) = Cross[Subscript[x, s], Subscript[x, ss]] = \[Kappa] 
(s, t) b (s)` and `X(s,t)`.

Comment: I think I've changed on the other part. Sorry. The same question. Again, sorry.